# Issue with directory access, tomcat server 9.0

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been facing the issue, of not getting access to the directory, because of which i have changed the instalation directory from (C: to F:) drive, i know it didn't help :( , While earlier the directory used to open, because of which i am not abe to set the server in intellij IDE, eclipse IDE, not able to give them access of Catalin_home and Catalina_base, which is required.

I want to ask, that is this thing occurs to every windows user, when installed first time?
I can get acces to it using continue, but applivations such a intellij, eclipse didn't get it, which leads to hosting issues.

BTW, the localhost is running while running the server, and i can log in and upload file thier and deploy.

so, after seeing images (2 to 5), you can see, that the files inside tomcat directory are accessible, but other ide's are not able to find , due to image 1, i guesss!..

[Problem while accessing the tomcat installed directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7Gp.png)

[localhost running after service started, photo 1--running tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqXU1.png)

[Photo after loggin in after clicking manager app , photo 2--logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRdX7.png)

[I will upload a sample war file, which is provided by tomcat to check tomcat server, photo 3--uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RvGP.png)

[To access the deployed war file, embed /war_file_name, as i did, it was deployed and it runned, photo 4--deployed and running, sample war file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmuBI.png)

Comment: From review. Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Your question should show your effort to solve the task. Code is good, environment, screenshots (which you have), error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok, thank you so much , but i have followed all the rules of asking question, i believe i will grow, as i ask more questions.